# Will The Number of Class Projects Affect the Performance for a Silverlight Web Solution

Tags: silverlight, performance, web-applications

I'm currently working on a Silverlight project, and I have created a Silverlight Web Solution, which contains a main Silverlight Application and several class projects.

My question is:

Will the number of class projects affect the performance?  (For better management, I divided my non UI stuff into several projects)

Thanks.

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) premature optimization is the root of all evil
>
> -Donald Knuth

2) It will have some minor impact on (at least) load times when the service is accessed the first time. The startup of the silverlight component won't be affected, nor the access time for subsequent accesses.

3) as long as you don't go crazy I doubt it will be human noticeable